# How to pass a function that calls a two dimensional array as a parameter?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans

```
char board[][]=printBoard(board);
  printBoard(board);


 public char[][] printBoard (char [][] test){
    char[][] game = {

     {'_','1','2','3'}, 
     {'1','_', '_', '_'},
     {'2','_', '_', '_'},
     {'3','_', '_', '_'}
  };
  return game; 
}
```

Hi, I am was wondering how to call my printBoard function? Nothing in printBoard is highlighted in red so I think the problem is that I am not calling it correctly. Thanks for the help.I'm trying to put the board in it's own function and then call it by using the 2d array variable board[][]. I'm trying to make a tic tac toe game. When i run this it doesn't print the board.

Comment: A few issues: you never call any IO functions (eg: `System.out.print()`, `System.out.println()`. You make absolutely no use of the `char[][] test` that gets passed into printBoard. And you call `printBoard(board)` before `board` is defined. Then it is called again for some reason. There's a lot going on that's not quite right here, and it's very confusing what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You simply never call any print method, you just allocate an array. Below is an example of how to do it:

```
char board[][] = {
     {'_','1','2','3'}, 
     {'1','_', '_', '_'},
     {'2','_', '_', '_'},
     {'3','_', '_', '_'}
};

for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(board[i][j] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: public char[][] printBoard (char [][] gainz){
        
        for (int i = 0; i < gainz.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gainz[i].length; j++) {
               System.out.print(gainz[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
         }
      return gainz; 
    }                                                                                                               my mistake. Ok, so i want to basically put that for statement in its own function and call it. How would i do that? Would it look like this?I'm not sure how to call this function.

Comment: I'm sorry dude but this is the kind of things the first tutorial on Google will tell you. Try harder, and if you really don't manage to do it come back here with what you attempted

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this:

```
char board[][]=printBoard(board);
```

declare an object and assigning with the return of a method that is taking itself as argument... what is this??

the argument must be some 2d array different...

Answer (score 0):

Your "printBoard" method does not acutely print the the array, just allocking it like Dici said. To print the array I would use a double for loop. Below is an example.

```
public class Averagegrades 
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    char board[][]= setBoard();
    printBoard(board);
}

public static char[][] setBoard (){
    char[][] test = {

            {'_','1','2','3'}, 
            {'1','_', '_', '_'},
            {'2','_', '_', '_'},
            {'3','_', '_', '_'}
    };
    return test; 
}

public static void printBoard(char[][] board){
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```